# Using Group by having values in two or more "IN clauses" (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I've got a table in  SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Customer_ID  Store_ID   date 
12334        11111111   12.12.2017
14446        11111111   12.12.2017 
10551        22222222   12.12.2017  
10691        22222222   12.12.2017  
10295        33333333   12.12.2017 
10295        33333333   10.12.2017 
10195        44444444   22.12.2017
```

and what I need is a list of distinct `Customer_ID` which will have `Store_ID` in both  "`IN` clauses", first is `(11111111, 44444444)` and second is `(22222222, 33333333)`.

As for now I guess that I should write a query that will `SELECT Customer_id` using `GROUP BY`, but I'm not sure how to write `HAVING` clause.

Any thoughts on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Your explanation of the logic is confusing...  And the only way I can understand it suggests that from your given dataset, no `Customer_ID` will actually be returned?

Comment: I guess in last row `Customer_ID` should equal to `10295` and then desired result would be `10295`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Customer_ID from Tbl
where Store_ID in (11111111, 44444444)
intersect
select Customer_ID from Tbl
where Store_ID in (22222222, 33333333)
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete guess, but... maybe???

```
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Customer_ID
HAVING (COUNT(CASE Store_ID WHEN 11111111 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND  COUNT(CASE Store_ID WHEN 44444444 THEN 1 END) > 0)
    OR (COUNT(CASE Store_ID WHEN 22222222 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND  COUNT(CASE Store_ID WHEN 33333333 THEN 1 END) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try EXIST

```
select 
 distinct customer_id 
from t t1 
  where
exists(

      select 1 
      from t t2 
      where t2.customer_id =t1.customer_id 
          and t2.store_id in (11111111, 44444444)
      )
and t1.store_id in (2222222,33333333)
```

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/JKT49446)**</kbd>